# update_client_config_error error in VueStrorefront + vsf-payment-paypal

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-storefront

I'm a beginner in Vue Storefront. I'm trying to integrate Paypal to Vue Storefront. I have followed all steps in read me of this package (`vsf-payment-paypal`). But I'm stuck on this following error for two days,

```
update_client_config_error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property \'find\' of undefined at VueComponent.grandTotal (http://localhost:3000/dist/vsf-checkout.js:1446:25)
```

Any idea how to fix this issue? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Dealing with same issues for Hours in NodeJS and i was able to fix it the issue is on Your Json not in PayPal configurations.

```
let order;
                try 
                {
                  order = await client.execute(request);
                  let response = {
                    statusCode: '200',
                    body: JSON.stringify({ orderID: order.result.id }),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    }
                };
                  return JSON.stringify({ orderID: order.result.id });
                } 
                catch (err) 
                {
                  console.error(err);

                  let response = {
                    statusCode: '500',
                    body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'Something Went Wrong While Creating Order..!' }),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    }
                };
                  return response;

                }
```

this is how i modify my return on nodejs server side

> body: JSON.stringify({ orderID: order.result.id })

and this is my Create Order function

```
      createOrder: function() {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/PayPal/Pay', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(function(res) {
      return res.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log("data.orderID" +data);

      return data.orderID; // Use the same key name for order ID on the client and server
    });
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container')});
```

Sorry i Don't know anything about Vue so i can't help with that. but hope this will help you ..! Good luck